# Semi Transparent Activity like Popup window

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make Semi Transaparent Activity Like pop window i.e. As my appActivity starts one pop up window on top that should come and user should click proceed button to go on that activity. I have seen dialog as well as Alert Box but they are widget. I want to use the screen as activity so that I can put xml layout .

I have come across PopWindow but I do not know how to use it .I have made one class  PopupWindow When I try to achieve findviewbyid I am unable to achieve it becoz PopupWindow class is not extending anything ....

So what should i use if popWindow class then how to use it ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

create an layout as you like to have as a dialogue and create an activity using that layout.
in the manifest declare that activity and add android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog in that activity stub.